# How can I loop through an object and sum the amount to each payment type?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a project in JavaScript and I want to sum up the amounts made by each payment mode to that payment type e.g by cash, card or customer account.

I want the table to look like this 
Payment Type --------Amount
 
Cash---------------------30 
Card----------------------200 
Account------------ -----2000

When I run this code

```ts
// Get sales for curent period
getSalesBetween(startTime_b: string, endTime_a: string) {

    if (this._sales) {
        return Promise.resolve(this._sales);
    }

    let startTime = "PAY_" + startTime_b;
    if (!endTime_a) {
        this.endTime_b = startTime;
    } else {
        this.endTime_b = "PAY_" + endTime_a;
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        this.db.query('my_sales_payments_by_date', {
            startkey: startTime,
            endkey: this.endTime_b + '\ufff0',
            include_docs: true
        }).then((result) => {

            console.log('Get sales:: ', JSON.stringify(result));

            this._sales = [];
            this.payment = [];
            let tcash = 0,
                tcard = 0,
                tacc = 0,
                total = 0;
            let paymentType = '';
            let i = 0;

            result.rows.map(row => {
                total = total + row.doc.amount;
                paymentType = row.doc.paymentOption;
                console.log("Total:: ", total);


                if (row.doc.paymentOption = 'cash') {
                    paymentType = 'Cash';
                    tcash = tcash + +row.doc.amount;
                    console.log('cash - ' + row.doc.amount)
                } else if (row.doc.paymentOption = 'card') {
                    paymentType = 'Card';
                    tcard = tcard + +row.doc.amount;
                    console.log('Card - ' + row.doc.amount)
                } else if (row.doc.paymentOption = 'account') {
                    paymentType = 'Account'
                    tacc = tacc + +row.doc.amount;
                    console.log('Account - ' + row.doc.amount)
                }

            });

            this.payment.push({
                paymentType: paymentType,
                tcash: tcash,
                tcard: tcard,
                tacc: tacc,
                tcashp: this.percentage(tcash, total),
                tcardp: ((tcard / total) * 100).toFixed(2),
                taccp: ((tacc / total) * 100).toFixed(2)
            })

            resolve(this.payment);


            this.db.changes({
                live: true,
                since: 'now',
                include_docs: true
            }).on('change', this.onDatabaseChange);
        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log(error);
            resolve(false);

        });

    }).catch((error) => {

        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I am just getting the first result:
Payment Type --------Amount
 
Cash---------------------30

JSON data

```js
{  
   "total_rows":59,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
         "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
         "value":110,
         "doc":{  
            "paymentStatus":true,
            "paymentOption":"card",
            "amount":110,
            "tenderedTotal":110,
            "time":"2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
            "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
            "type":"payment",
            "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
            "_rev":"1-9fdc73a415914311a80db1727fbc593b"
         }
      },
      {  
         "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
         "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
         "value":66,
         "doc":{  
            "paymentStatus":true,
            "paymentOption":"cash",
            "amount":66,
            "tenderedTotal":66,
            "time":"2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
            "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
            "type":"payment",
            "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
            "_rev":"1-a58e3811d11c4ca3a92bd1e206e6e0f3"
         }
      },
      {  
         "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
         "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
         "value":60,
         "doc":{  
            "paymentStatus":true,
            "paymentOption":"account",
            "amount":60,
            "tenderedTotal":152,
            "time":"2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
            "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
            "type":"payment",
            "fromCustomerAccount":true,
            "customerPayment":false,
            "grandTotal":60,
            "customer":{  
               "type":"account",
               "account_type":"customer",
               "fname":"Mukopaje",
               "lname":"Singogo",
               "phone":"974776247",
               "email":"mukopaje@gmail.com",
               "region":"Other",
               "city":"Lusaka",
               "balance":0,
               "status":true,
               "index":0,
               "_id":"CST_2019-01-03T11:27:22.924Z",
               "_rev":"4-9453c05f151242a39bc5511323bbb820"
            },
            "customerPaid":152,
            "customer_id":"CST_2019-01-03T11:27:22.924Z",
            "credeb":"debit",
            "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
            "_rev":"1-0486777aaf1444bdaa8bcd35dd18c1d9"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I make this work? Any help I will really appreciate

Comment: can you post the JSON

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code! At a glance:
 - In your `if`, you're doing `row.doc.paymentOption = 'cash'` rather than `row.doc.paymentOption === 'cash'
 - You're pushing to `this.payment` only once, rather than in the loop

Comment: @AshayMandwarya I have posted the JSON data

Comment: @Sophie thanks let me do some changes and see what the code does now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you need?

```
let cash = 0;
let card = 0;
let account = 0;

for (const row of result.rows) {
  switch (row.doc.paymentOption) {
    case 'cash':
      cash += row.doc.amount;
      break;
    case 'card':
      card += row.doc.amount;
      break;
    case 'account':
      account += row.doc.amount;
      break;
    default:
      // Error
  }
}

console.log(`Cash: ${cash}`);
console.log(`Card: ${card}`);
console.log(`Account: ${account}`);
```

This is assuming that the `row.doc.amount` field always contains a valid numerical value.

Comment: What if another payment type is added apart from cash, card or account?? You cannot use switch statements as they are not modular

Comment: @AshayMandwarya That's true, but the question was about how to sum the amounts of each type of payment option. You won't always necessarily want to include all possible payment options, and you might want to actively discount/call attention to invalid options. Since the requirements weren't that specific, I just tried to answer the question as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this-
It iterates through the row property and gets the type and value of payment. If the payment type is already in object it adds to it else it creates the property.

```js
var obj={  
    "total_rows":59,
    "offset":0,
    "rows":[  
       {  
          "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
          "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
          "value":110,
          "doc":{  
             "paymentStatus":true,
             "paymentOption":"card",
             "amount":110,
             "tenderedTotal":110,
             "time":"2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
             "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
             "type":"payment",
             "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T12:18:52.085Z",
             "_rev":"1-9fdc73a415914311a80db1727fbc593b"
          }
       },
       {  
          "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
          "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
          "value":66,
          "doc":{  
             "paymentStatus":true,
             "paymentOption":"cash",
             "amount":66,
             "tenderedTotal":66,
             "time":"2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
             "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
             "type":"payment",
             "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T16:27:29.553Z",
             "_rev":"1-a58e3811d11c4ca3a92bd1e206e6e0f3"
          }
       },
       {  
          "key":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
          "id":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
          "value":60,
          "doc":{  
             "paymentStatus":true,
             "paymentOption":"account",
             "amount":60,
             "tenderedTotal":152,
             "time":"2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
             "orderId":"ORD_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
             "type":"payment",
             "fromCustomerAccount":true,
             "customerPayment":false,
             "grandTotal":60,
             "customer":{  
                "type":"account",
                "account_type":"customer",
                "fname":"Mukopaje",
                "lname":"Singogo",
                "phone":"974776247",
                "email":"mukopaje@gmail.com",
                "region":"Other",
                "city":"Lusaka",
                "balance":0,
                "status":true,
                "index":0,
                "_id":"CST_2019-01-03T11:27:22.924Z",
                "_rev":"4-9453c05f151242a39bc5511323bbb820"
             },
             "customerPaid":152,
             "customer_id":"CST_2019-01-03T11:27:22.924Z",
             "credeb":"debit",
             "_id":"PAY_2019-01-11T18:12:13.716Z",
             "_rev":"1-0486777aaf1444bdaa8bcd35dd18c1d9"
          }
       }
    ]
 }
 var a=obj.rows;
 var k={};
 a.forEach((e)=>{
 if(!k.hasOwnProperty(e.doc.paymentOption))
 {
k[e.doc.paymentOption]=0;    
}
if(k.hasOwnProperty(e.doc.paymentOption))
{
    k[e.doc.paymentOption]=Number(k[e.doc.paymentOption])+Number(e.value);
}
})
 console.log(k)
```